# Visual Basic MySql Connection string

Tags: mysql, vba, exception, connection-string

I am using MySQL connection string to connect to a MySQL database in my current project.

> Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=12345;Database=test;

But the connection throws ecxeption when one of the paremeters contain ; symbol. For example:

> Pwd=12;345

Exception:

> Keyword not supported.
>   Parameter name: 345;Database

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string at [here](http://connectionstrings.com/)

And your pasword looks like contain illegal value for MySQL..
Just look at your code.

e.g `Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=12345;Database=test;`
before Pwd, it have already has ; then after your password, it still have ;
so, it means that password start from ";" and end at ";" again.
So, the best suggestions is change your password.
Hope will be help

Comment: I need to find out a way to use that symbol in pasword and pass it trough the Connection string!

Comment: then try this.. 'Pwd="123;45";Data...'

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your password in double quotes.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28VS.71%29.aspx under the Remarks section about a third of the way down.

> The basic format of a connection string consists of a series of keyword/value pairs separated by semicolons. The equal sign (=) connects each keyword and its value. To include values that contain a semicolon, single-quote character, or double-quote character, the value must be enclosed in double quotes. If the value contains both a semicolon and a double-quote character, the value can be enclosed in single quotes. The single quote is also useful if the value begins with a double-quote character. Conversely, the double quote can be used if the value begins with a single quote. If the value contains both single-quote and double-quote characters, the quote character used to enclose the value must be doubled each time it occurs within the value.